# Android Background - Stretch - 9Patch Issue

Tags: android, background-image, nine-patch

I built an image, did what is necessary using 9Patch, and applied it as a background image for a ScollView.

The image displayed as stretched, well thats what I want. But it didn't stretch in the way 9-Patch showed. It streatches the image kind of disregarding the information I have fed through 9-Patch. Any way I can correct this?

```
android:background="@drawable/phonebg"
```

Well, what I am trying to achieve is to have some thing like a Logo in the bottom of the screen. It also has a small design in the corners of the screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: upload your image and post the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you named your image `image_name.9.png` file name

Comment: Its the first time I used 9-Gag, and I renamed the file and removed the 9 part from it and copied it to the res folder. Once I put it back, it worked! Thanks a lot!